# Why does rendering over a transparent background create artifacts not present when the background is coloured. Python Gizeh Moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

'''
[The image with strange behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hELmp.png)
[The discs looking 'normal' when using a background on the gizeh surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeP2I.png)

Hi. I am using the above code snippet to get a series of frames of a gizeh surface with some discs drawn on it. The following is the make frame function which is causing the problem.

```
def make_frame(t):
    
    surface = gizeh.Surface(1080,1080,bg_color=(0.2,0.5,0.2,1.0))
    #draw border
    border_width= 40.00
    Border=gizeh.rectangle(1080, 1080, xy=((1080//2,1080//2)), stroke = (1.0,1.0,1.0), stroke_width = border_width)
    Border.draw(surface)
    for disc in discs:
        Ball_w=gizeh.circle(r=(disc.size), xy=[disc.position[0] ,disc.position[1]], fill= (disc.color))
        Ball_w.draw(surface)
        disc.collide_with_wall(table_width, table_height, border_width)
        #disc.collide_with_disc(discs)
        disc.move()
    return surface.get_npimage(transparent=True)
```

When I use moviepy to pull all the clips into a short .5..5 sec clip everything works as expected for the above code. However when I set the background to transparent by changing the surface bg color from

```
bg_color=(0.2,0.5,0.2,1.0)  .... to this .... bg_color=(0.2,0.5,0.2,0.0)
```

The discs, which are moving show strange areas in front of the disc, in the direction the disc is moving. Also there is some strange leeching of color from one disc to another when they overlap. The two pictures show the issue (solid background , good. transparent background, bad). I have tried partial tranparency, and very very small numbers above 0 and just below 1 for the Alpha channel but the artifacts/leeching persist. I am at a total loss as to how to address this. I can share any further code you may wish to see. Two useful snippets may be the following. Disc Class.

```
class Disc:
    def __init__(self, size, density, position, velocity, color):
        self.size = size
        self.density = density
        self.mass = size*size*density
        self.position = position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.color = color
    def move(self):
        # Update the position of the disc based on its velocity
        self.position[0] = (self.position[0] + self.velocity[0])
        self.position[1] = (self.position[1] + self.velocity[1])
        #self.position[0] = self.velocity[0] + self.position[0]
        #self.position[1] = self.velocity[1] + self.position[1]
    def update_position(self, new_position):
        self.position = new_position
    def update_velocity(self, new_velocity):
        self.velocity = new_velocity
    def collide_with_wall(self, width, height, border_width):
        # Check for collisions with the walls of the pool table
        if self.position[0] <=0+self.size+border_width/2:
            self.velocity[0] =abs(self.velocity[0])  # Reverse the x-direction velocity
    
        if self.position[0] >= width-self.size-border_width/2:
            self.velocity[0] =-abs(self.velocity[0])  # Reverse the x-direction velocity
        
        if self.position[1] <=0+self.size+border_width/2:
            self.velocity[1] =abs(self.velocity[1])  # Reverse the y-direction velocity

        if self.position[1] >= height-self.size-border_width/2:
            self.velocity[1] =-abs(self.velocity[1])  # Reverse the y-direction velocity
```

This is the function that gets all the frames, pulls them together and sends them to the main function which uses this and other moviepy clips to produce a final video. Everything else in the program is working fine. I'm happy to do any heavy lifting on research but I've not seen this issue referred to anywhere and fear that a resolution will involve delving into the workings of Cairo, (which wouldn't be simple for me, even if I knew what to look for). Any suggestions on this would be grateful. I'm stumped.

```
        for frame_no in range (0, int(num_frames)):
            clip=get_array_clip(discs,frame_no)
            palette_clip.append(clip)
        final_vid=concatenate_videoclips(palette_clip, method="chain" )
        final_vid.set_start(palette_start_time)
        clip=[]
        clip.append(final_vid.set_start(palette_start_time).set_position((0,420)))
        return clipenter image description here
```

Comment: The images I added to not appear to be carried through. Probably my bad, I'm a newb. Will try to remedy asap.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Summary:::Pic 2. Working fine, the image is  a still and the discs are moving around the box as expected. Pic 1, the only change is to make the green background transparent. As you can see I now have those black edges (not wanted) and strange colour leeching from one object to another. (by the way, in case relevant, the change in disc colours will take place every time I run the program, this works fine, and has done from the start of writing the program so the changing disc colours is not related to the source of the issue.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I probably over did the 'info' download rather than stating the problem simply. I've seen some people get ripped here because they don't put enough information down. Hopefully I've avoided that one on my first post.